# Is it possible to hide the taskbar program icons on secondary monitors for Gnome 3 (Dash to Panel)?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, icons, launcher

Desired result:

- On my main monitor I want the program icons (launchers) as well as a tab for each open window.
- On secondary monitors I only want a tab for each open window and no launchers.

Currently, all monitors have the full taskbar with launchers and tabs.